# For what primes $p$ is $ (x + y)^{13} \equiv x^{13} + y^{13} \pmod{p}$, $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It is clear that $2$ and $13$ are valid values for $p$, but I can not think of any approach that would yield all possible $p$.

Comment: @Surb what about $p=2$?

Comment: @Surb  or $p=5$ for that matter.

Comment: Note:  maybe this just dates me, but I read $\mathbb Z_p$ as the $p-$adic integers.  I expect that here you intend $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $x=y=1$, then the congruence implies that $$2^{13}\equiv 2\pmod{p}$$

If you take $x=2, y=1$, then the congruence implies that $$3^{13}\equiv 2^{13}+1\equiv 3\pmod{p}$$

Continuing in this way, we find that, for all $0\le k<p$, $$k^{13}\equiv k\pmod{p}$$

In particular, the polynomial $x^{13}-x$ has $p$ roots modulo $p$.  We factor $$x^{13}-x=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$$
This needs to have $p$ linear factors for any $p$ that works.  We see immediately $p=2, 3$ work. Also, $p=13$ is the maximum possible $p$ that could work (and must, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)).  For $p$ between $5,13$, we simply check to see if it has $p$ distinct roots.

Followup: $p=2,3,5,7,13$ work; $p=11$ does not.  This is easily computed with [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E13+-x+modulo+7).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you very much.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field with $p$ members and a polynomial form of degree $13$ on a field has at most $13$ zeroes.  Since $x^{13}-x$ has $p$ zeroes in $\Bbb  Z_p$, therefore  $p\leq 13.$.............+1

Comment: Regarding $p\ne 11$: We have $2^{13}\not \equiv 2\pmod {11}:$ "By hand": $11\not |\; 8190=2^{13}-2$ because $11 \not |\;(8-1+9-0).$.. or "by FLT" : Mod $11$ we have $2^{13}\equiv 2^{10}\cdot2^3\equiv 2^3\equiv 8\not\equiv 2.$

Comment: I can't resist one more comment . For  $k^{13}-k\equiv 0 \pmod p$ to have $p$ distinct solutions modulo $p,$ it suffices that  $k^{12}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ for $1\leq k\leq p-1.$ By FLT, if prime $p<12$ this holds if $(p-1)| 12, $ which holds for $p\in \{2,3,5,7\}$

Answer (score 6):

If it must hold for every $x,y\in\mathbb Z_p$ then in particular it must hold for $x=y=1$, and this is only true if $p\mid 2^{13}-2=8190$. So $p\in \{2,3,5,7,13\}$ and you can check these by trying all possible $x,y$.

Comment: This is wonderful! Thank you very much.